# Python: Unique CSV output each time through for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a for loop which is performing some preprocessing and at the end of the loop I would like to output to csv. I can get it to output, however, it overwrites each time. I want a unique file each time. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=('Full_Name'))
    df = df[(df.Draft_Year>2003) & (df.Draft_Year<2022)]
    df = df.drop(['Position','College','Draft_Year'], axis=1)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
    imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
    df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df),columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
    df = df.to_csv(r"D:\Model Data\Exports\NFL Draft Model\processed.csv", index=True, header=True)`
```

Comment: Then you need to provide a unique file name each time.  Perhaps [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use the original file name in your output :

```
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=('Full_Name'))
    df = df[(df.Draft_Year>2003) & (df.Draft_Year<2022)]
    df = df.drop(['Position','College','Draft_Year'], axis=1)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
    imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
    df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df),columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
    df = df.to_csv(fr"D:\Model Data\Exports\NFL Draft Model\{filename.name.split('.')[0]}_processed.csv", index=True, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write different file names each time. One way could be as follows:

```
i = 1    
for filename in os.scandir(directory):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=('Full_Name'))
        df = df[(df.Draft_Year>2003) & (df.Draft_Year<2022)]
        df = df.drop(['Position','College','Draft_Year'], axis=1)
        scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
        imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
        df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df),columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
        df = df.to_csv(f"D:\Model Data\Exports\NFL Draft Model\processed{i}.csv", index=True, header=True)
        i+=1
```